# summing a series of numbers entered by the user

Tags: sum

I'm learning from a book and here is my task:

> Write a program to sum a series of numbers entered by the user. The
>   program should first prompt the user for how many numbers are to be
>   summed. It should then input each of the numbers and print a total
>   sum.

I have pretty much no idea how to start on this. My first problem is just after the user definies how many numbers are to be summed, I don't know how to make use of the information to build the next input expression for exact numbers.

If we knew before how many numbers the user will enter this would be no brainer but...

Comment: Use a loop and an array.

Comment: Hint: you'll have to use some programming language.

Comment: Array is not really needed in this case, though.

Comment: I haven't yet coverd an array usage. Any other way? the for loop you mean?

Comment: isn't the clue in the book?

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and a variable to hold the sum.

Comment: alright so if you can actually gimme the direct answer would be cool bc im stuck with it apparently

Comment: We're not trying to be haughty or anything, but just giving you the answer woulod teach you nothing. You're supposed to learn from this. What does a loop do? How does it work? Give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help so far in the comments.

I came up with this code, it does give the correct answer but it prompts the user to enter his numbers `how_many` number of times each time asking and printing the `Enter exact numbers` phrase. It would be desired to fix it that way that the user can enter the numbers once with a comma. Any suggestions?

```
def main():
    sum = 0
    how_many = input("How many numbers are to be entered? ")
    for i in range(how_many):
        numbers = input("Enter exact numbers: ")
        sum = numbers + sum

    print "The sum equals to", sum

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    n = eval(input("Enter how many numbers you want to enter: \n"))
    ssum = 0

    for i in range(n):
        k = eval(input("Enter a number: \n"))
        ssum = k + ssum

    print("Sum of the above numbers is: ", ssum)

main()
```